# Can a Planetar, Solar, or Deva learn new spells beyond their innate spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

I saw that there are certain "innate spells" that various kinds of celestials can use. Could a specific planetar/solar/deva (one of the angel ones, basically) NPC have other spells at their disposal?

"Innate" makes me think that it’s a universal trait, and I haven't seen anything that said they couldn't learn more, but I could've just missed it. Mainly I'm thinking of one of these angelic NPCs having spells like fabrication, teleportation, and/or gate.

Answer (score 8):

## The DM determines what spells a particular creature has as part of its innate spellcasting trait.

The Monster Manual lists these restrictions on the innate spellcasting trait:

> INNATE SPELLCASTING
>
> A monster with the innate ability to cast spells has the Innate Spellcasting special trait. [...] An innate spell can have special rules or restrictions. [...] A monster's innate spells can't be swapped out with other spells. [...]

But as with everything in D&D Rule 0 is always in effect, the DM is free to change any “rule” they want. This is doubly true when they are creating Monsters.

So once a DM has determined what spells a particular instance of a creature, with the Innate Spellcasting trait, has (eg Bob the Solar), that particular creature’s spells are fixed.

They do not, however, have to be the spells listed in the Monster Manual stat block. The DM is free to change those spells when they are creating Bob the Solar for any reason they desire.

For example, in a given DMs world a particular god may have imbued their Solar/Panetar/Deva minions with a particular set of spells when they willed their horde of angels into being.

As a counterpoint to the Innate Spellcasting trait, Monsters can also have the Spellcasting class feature. For example, the Lich is described as an 18th level spellcaster (ie they have the Spellcasting class feature). As such you would expect a particular Lich (Alice the Lich) to be able to swap out their spells from encounter to encounter.

### What is the effect of changing a creature’s spells from those in the stat block?

If you, as the DM, change the spells for a creature from those in its stat block you should be aware that this can, sometimes drastically (depending on what you have changed), change how difficult that particular creature is to beat.

Guidelines on how to calculate this change in difficulty are presented in the Dungeon Masters Guide.

Using your example of giving the Gate spell (a 9th level spell) to an angelic being. This potentially significantly ramps up their combat power levels (depending on what you’ve swapped it for) as it could easily result in giving them a one shot, no save, kill on a PC that can’t innately fly.<sup>1</sup>

Procedure for one shot kill with Gate:

1. Open 20ft diameter portal centred immediately under a PC with that portal going to the outermost regions of the Plane of Fire (where all the really nasty stuff is).
2. Immediately stop concentration on the Gate spell as soon as the PC falls through the gate.

#### Rule 0

Players Handbook:

> Your DM might set the campaign on one of these worlds or on one that he or she created. Because there is so much diversity among the worlds of D&D, you should check with your DM about any house rules that will affect your play of the game. Ultimately, the Dungeon Master is the authority on the campaign and its setting, even if the setting is a published world.

Dungeon Masters Guide

> And as a referee, the DM interprets the rules and decides when to abide by them and when to change them.

Monster Manual

> Guidelines for creating encounters with monsters can be found in the Dungeon Master's Guide. That book also contains wandering monster tables and other goodies to help you use the monsters in this book in interesting ways, as well as advice for modifying monsters and creating your own.

---

1. This assumes you’ve put no specific restrictions on their Gate spell of course.

Comment: I think I'd probably allow a Dex save to move/grab onto a handhold to save yourself from that Gate tactic. But that's DM interpretation.